# What, exactly, does ssh-copy-id do?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

What does the ssh-copy-id command do, exactly?  I've used it numerous times and it works great.  However, when I try to manually cut and paste my .pub keyfile to my remote authorized_keys, it doesn't work.

I've compared the contents of my authorized_keys file where I've cut and pasted the .pub into it vs subsequently using ssh-copy-id and I'm not seeing any differences between the two, including whitespace.

Is there anything that ssh-copy-id does beyond copying the public key into authorized_keys?

Comment: Did you check if the permissions for `authorized_keys` are set up correctly?

Comment: Yes, permissions on the directory and authorized_keys were both correct.  ssh-copy-id inserted into the same file as my cut and paste so the file environment is identical.  I'm mostly curious if there's any other action that ssh-copy-id does to 'activate' the key on the remote server.  If not, I need to figure out how my cut and paste is altering the public key.

Comment: Perhaps a try a `diff` between your version and the automated version?  The man page for `ssh-copy-id` doesn't say it does anything else.  Plus, `ssh-copy-id` is just an ordinary shell script so you could examine to see what it does.

Answer (score 33):

This little one liner script works on sh, bash, and zsh. I use it every time there is no ssh-copy-id, for example when I'm on older version of OSX.

```bash
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh <user>@<hostname> 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

**How it works**

I am sending the public key to the Unix standard output (STDOUT) using the `cat` command. I then connect the STDOUT of `cat` to the standard input (STDIN) of the `ssh`.

The `ssh` executes the `cat` command on the server. Remember that we have our key in the STDIN now? This key gets passed from ssh to the `cat` command executed on a server. The `>>` operator redirects the STDOUT of the cat to the end of the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. This way, the key from public keys is appended to the `authorized_keys` on the server.

IMO, it's better than manual copying and pasting: in this case, you know exactly what content will end up in the file.

Answer (score 8):

I usually copy-paste keys into authorized_keys as you describe (I forget about `ssh-copy-id`), so it can work. Note that`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is required if you're creating the file.

`ssh-copy-id` is a shell script so you can open it in a text editor to see what it does, this looks like the relevant bit:

```
printf '%s\n' "$NEW_IDS" | ssh "$@" "
    umask 077 ;
    mkdir -p .ssh && cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys || exit 1 ;
    if type restorecon >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then restorecon -F .ssh .ssh/authorized_keys ; fi"
```

[restorecon](https://www.mankier.com/8/restorecon) in the last line restores default SELinux security contexts. I haven't had to run that, but it might be necessary in your case.

Comment: FYI, I created a small script at https://github.com/centic9/generate-and-send-ssh-key which runs the necessary steps in one go and additionally ensures all the file/directory permissions which usually always caused me headaches...

Comment: @JacksonPauls can you provide a source for this statement that you said: "`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is required if you're creating the file"? I searched in the script and didn't see any code like that. I also experienced inconsistent results while testing.