# ssh-copy-id on windows doesn't work: No such file or directory

Tags: windows, ssh, git-bash

I want to copy public keys to my server from a windows system.
And the problem I have is, that I don't get the path to the key. 
I've tried things like:

```
ssh-copy-id -i C:/Users/username/.ssh/mykey.pub user@serverIP

ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/mykey.pub user@serverIP
```

The result is always

> No such file or directory

What am I doing wrong? I'm using *Git Bash* for this on *Windows 10*

Answer (score 13):

Git's ssh is a version of [OpenSSH](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/openssh/). You can confirm it by running `ssh -V` under `path\to\git\usr\bin`. Here is what it evals on my machine:

```
OpenSSH_7.7p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018
```

`ssh-copy-id` script internally executes some *nix shell command (like `exec`, `cat`, etc. You can find more by opening the one under `path\to\git\usr\bin` in text mode), so it works only against *nix machines. That's the reason why `ssh-copy-id` under `path\to\git\usr\bin` is not a executable file.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1467) of [PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH), `ssh-copy-id` is not supported on Windows.

However, there are some alternative ways to do the same thing:

A powershell version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27248468/10315163) can be

```bsh
Get-Content $env:USERPROFILE\.ssh\id_rsa.pub | ssh <user>@<hostname> "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

There is also a python script to do the same thing: [ssh-copy-id for Windows](https://gist.github.com/ceilfors/fb6908dc8ac96e8fc983).