# how to configure Password less authentication With Git Client and git server?

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

After Running ssh-keygen in git bash when I am executing

```sh
$ scp id_rsa.pub kovair@192.168.12.232:.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I am getting

```
The authenticity of host '192.168.12.232 (192.168.12.232)' can't be established.

ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:v9aX9gU44tKMXefUA1V2bgPVzP1PoICupP+cpU3sNB4.

Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes

Warning: Permanently added '192.168.12.232' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

kovair@192.168.12.232's password:

id_rsa.pub                                                  100%  403     3.2KB/s   00:00
```

After this when I an trying to verify weather passwordless authentication  is successful or not using

```
$ ssh kovair@192.168.12.232 ls
```

I am getting this

```
kovair@192.168.12.232's password:
```

It should not ask for password I guess in this step.

What am I doing wrong can anyone help?

Comment: Run ssh command with `-vvv` to check debug output.

Comment: Hint: next time use `ssh-copy-id` instead of `scp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command after executing $ scp id_rsa.pub kovair@192.168.12.232:.ssh/authorized_keys

> “ ssh {username}@{host:port}  “chmod 700 .ssh ; chmod 640
> .ssh/authorized_keys” ”

and after successful execution run you command which is asking for password.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the rights associated to the created `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.
As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6377073/6309) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28916755/6309), it should be `600` (`rw-------`), and an scp might create the file with rights too open for SSH daemon to operate on.

That is why, as commented, [an `ssh-copy-id`](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/copy-id#copy-the-key-to-a-server) is preferable.